# Почему не работает eval("global a") в python?

Tags: python, eval

У меня еть строка "global a", где "a" переменная. Если написать код из одной только этой строки, то всё хорошо, но вот при попытке написать eval("global a") выскакивает ошибка

```
   global a
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Меня это поставило в ступор. Я много чего пытался сделать, что бы избежать ошибки, но она меня преследовала. Возможно я неправильно понимаю смысл функции eval() и она просто не способна на такое.
В оригинальной программе  я делал так:

```
for var in listik:
    eval("global " + str(var))
```

и всё равно ничего не работало. То есть у меня есть имя переменной (в списке), которую нужно сделать глобальной и eval, который не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Возможно eval() просто не может сделать такое или в моём случае есть какая-то более подходящая функция? 
Если что, то я знаю о опасности использования eval(), поэтому переменные у меня проверены и ничего плохого не произойдёт.

Comment: eval вычисляет выражение, но `global a` - это не выражение. Попробуйте exec.

Comment: вы можете предоставить пример, который генерирует ошибку .`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` ?

Comment: @insolor Спасибо. exec работает именно так как мне нужно